# Django authentication on a per-app basis

Tags: python, django, redirect, authentication, django-views

I am getting started with Django and I found something I don't understand very well when it comes to user authentication (using the typical [django.contrib.auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth) mechanism).

When I create a "[site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project)" using

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

I understand I create something like a "server". Then, I need to create an app (as explained in the "[getting started](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#creating-models)" tutorial). I create my models for the app, not for the server. The idea I have (which may be totally wrong) is that apps are something fairly independent among themselves (pretty isolated from each other). I create my models for each app, there is a different set of "views" per app, etc.

But when it comes to user management, that managing seems to be global for the whole project (or "server"): All the settings are specified through the global `settings.py` file, the built-in login pages are stored in the global `templates/` directory... What if I have two apps and I want the login pages for them to have a different aspect? What if after a successful login, I want to redirect to an specific page of *app#1* or to another specific page of *app#2* depending on the app the user was trying to log in? Maybe I am missunderstanding the whole concept behind a Django app?

Basically, I have a `mystartapp` application inside a project called `myserver`. I am using the built-in login view, sending a form to `"django.contrib.auth.views.login"`. With the default configuration, a successful login was trying to redirect me to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile/`, which I don't have.

I could find a workaround by editing the global `settings.py` file and the global `urls.py` files:

```
---------- settings.py ----------
[ . . . ]
# User Logging in Settings
LOGIN_URL = '/login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
[ . . . ]
---------------------------------
```

and

```
------------ urls.py ------------
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'myserver.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^myserver/', include('myserver.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    #The following line will include the urls for the "mystartapp" application 
    url(r'^s', include('mystartapp.urls', namespace="mystartapp")), #Dirty trick
    url(r'^mystartapp/', include('mystartapp.urls', namespace="mystartapp")),
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
)
------------------------------
```

This way, thanks to the 10th line (the one with the `#'Dirty trick'` comment), everything that goes to the root of `127.0.0.1:8000/` will be redirected to the same set of urls as if I used `127.0.0.1:8000/mystartapp/`, which combined with the  `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'` option in `settings.py`, will end up making the browser to redirect to `127.0.0.1:8080/mystartapp/index.html`, after a correct login but that doesn't seem "clean".

Is there a better way of establishing a redirection to `127.0.0.1:8080/mystartapp/index.html`? Is the dirty trick really a dirty trick or is it the way it's supposed to work? Am I missing something here?  (I'm pretty sure the answer to this last question is "Yes!", though)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason why using `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/mystartapp/index.html'` wouldn't work in your case?

---

Regarding the concept of apps, they are supposed to be independent bits of functionality (which is why they are sometimes labelled "reusable"). However, once you tie apps into a project, the goal is that they do work together at some point !

In the case of `contrib.auth`, this reusability is expressed by the parameters you used (such as `LOGIN_URL` or `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`), which allows you to configure the behavior of the app so it works in your project.

For instance, for a merchant side, you could use several apps to perform different actions related to your project:

- An app with your actual functionality (products, pages...)
- An app for search (like `django-solr`)
- An app for registration (`django-registration`)
- Contrib apps for authentication, session
- A merchant app for payments

The apps perform different bits of functionnality, but they all serve the same purpose and make up a project together.

---

If you need the apps to operate in a totally independent manner, they shouldn't be part of the same project in the first place! (Although you could use app A in projects P and Q, and app B only in P, for example).

Comment: Oh, that would probably work... I was wondering if that is the "right" way to do it. If the idea is having one server with several apps, wouldn't redirecting to an speific app's URL break the concept of isolated apps? (just wondering)

Comment: @BorrajaX I updated my answer to include a few pointers regarding that aspect.

Comment: Could you (I you may) provide a couple of examples of what a project with two or three aps would be? Could it be something like project == myOrganizationsSite, app1==blogSystem, app2==newsArea, app3==events? Something like that? Thank you

Comment: @BorrajaX I was actually writing one : )